# Functions as objects, apply method javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, module, apply

I am learning about javascript functions as objects, but I am struggling with this particular example that has to do with closure and modules.

```
var MyModules = (function Manager() 
    {
    var modules = {};
    function define(name, deps, impl) {
      for (var i=0; i<deps.length; i++) {
      deps[i] = modules[deps[i]];
    }
    modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );
    }
    function get(name) {
        return modules[name];
    }
    return {
       define: define,
       get: get
    };
})();
MyModules.define( "bar", [], function(){
    function hello(who) {
        return "Let me introduce: " + who;
    }
    return {
        hello: hello
    };
} );
MyModules.define( "foo", ["bar"], function(bar){
    var hungry = "hippo";
    function awesome() {
        console.log( bar.hello( hungry ).toUpperCase() ); 
    }
    return {
        awesome: awesome
    };
} ) 
var bar = MyModules.get( "bar" );
var foo = MyModules.get( "foo" );
console.log(bar.hello( "hippo" )); // Let me introduce: hippo
foo.awesome(); // LET ME INTRODUCE: HIPPO
```

Now, what i understand is the MyModules is an object, with attributes "define" and "get" that are functions. Module is an object with attribute as specified in the "name" argument of the define function which is a string, deps is an array of arguments, and impl is a function. Am I right?
What I dont understand is the

```
modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );
```

part. What does the apply method do? I know about the second argument, but what is the role of the function (object?? ) that calls the method, the role of the function that is accepted as an argument in apply method, the return value of the function and how is it related to those above?
The docs say:
Syntax

fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
Parameters

**thisArg**
The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

**argsArray**
An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which fun should be called, or null or undefined if no arguments should be provided to the function. Starting with ECMAScript 5 these arguments can be a generic array-like object instead of an array. See below for browser compatibility information.

**Return value**

The result of calling the function with the specified this value and arguments.

I wrote the whole code, as I don't know if I have understood it well and, did not want to give the wrong information.